# Nested SQL Queries: How to get multiple counts on same elements based on different criteria

Tags: sql

I have a table like this :

```
   Server     CompliancePercentage
   A          25
   B          15
   C          45
   D          75
   E          17
   F          82
```

I want to get from a single query the results in the following way:

```
   Conformity%        00-20   20-40   40-60  60-80   80-100
   Server Count       2       1          1     1      1
```

How do I get the above mentioned result from a nested query ?
Any help would be greatful.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Suvi

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: There are a number of questions similar to this already. Try searching on "sql buckets" for aggregation and "converting rows to columns" for the presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select
  'ServerCount' Conformity,
  count(case when CompliancePercentage >= 0 and CompliancePercentage <20 then 1 end) Per00_19,
  count(case when CompliancePercentage >= 20 and CompliancePercentage <40 then 1 end) Per20_39,
  count(case when CompliancePercentage >= 40 and CompliancePercentage <60 then 1 end) Per40_59,
  count(case when CompliancePercentage >= 60 and CompliancePercentage <80 then 1 end) Per60_79,
  count(case when CompliancePercentage >= 80 and CompliancePercentage <100 then 1 end) Per80_100
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10702d/1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following table:

```
create table dummyTable
(
    srv char(1),
    comp int
)
```

You can write out the query similar to

```
select 
    [00-19] = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dummyTable where comp between 0 and 19),
    [20-39] = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dummyTable where comp between 20 and 39)
```

If your table has a ton of records (ie, > 1M) you may want to consider adding a non-clustered index to the table on the compliance percentage column to avoid a bunch of table scans.

Comment: The `[alias] = expression` syntax is SQL-Server specific only.

Answer (score -1):

Something like that should works for you:

```
SELECT
    ( COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE id > 1 ) AS id_gt_1,
    ( COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE id > 100 ) AS id_gt_100
```

Here, the criteria I have matched is simply the count for the ID number.